# suspendThread in windows

Tags: multithreading, rtos

Keeping my question short... i am writing simulation for a RTOS. As usual the main problem comes with context switch simulation. In case of interrupts it is really becoming hard not to deviate from 'Good' coding guidelines.

Say Task A is running and user application is calculating its harmless private stuff which will run for a long time. during this task A, an interrupt X is supposed to occur. (hint: task A has nothing to do with triggering this interrupt X)... now how do i perform context switch from Task A to interrupt X handler?

My current implementation is based on a context thread that waits till some context switch is requested; an interrupt controller thread that can generate interrupts if someone request interrupt triggering; and a main thread that is running Task A. Now i use interrupt controller thread to generate a new thread for interrupt X and then request context thread to do the context switch. Context thread Suspends Task A main thread and resumes interrupt X handler thread. At the end of interrupt X handler thread, Task A main thread is resumed..

[Edit] just to clarify, i already know suspending and terminating threads from outside is really bad. That is why i asked this question. Plus please don't recommend using event etc. for controlling Task A. it is user application code and i can't control it. He can even use while(1){} if he wants...

Comment: wow you guys have enough time to click down vote but no time to answer the question... nicely done

Comment: A lot depends on the environment. Is this for Windows, or Linux for example? Do you have any control over the user code compiler? At present there probably isn't enough detail in the question to be able to provide any kind of decent answer.

Comment: Windows + Linux both...I can't control compiler... but i know they will use some standard MinGW or VS builds...any thing other required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you can't do what you want to do in that way.

You mentioned that suspending a thread from outside is really bad. The reason is that you have no idea what the thread is doing when you suspend it. It's impossible to know whether the thread currently owns a mutex; if it does then any other thread that tries to access the same mutex is going to deadlock.

You have the problem that the runtime being used by the threads that might be suspended is the same as the one being used by the supervisor. That means there are many potential such deadlocks between the supervisor and the other threads.

In a real environment (i.e. not a simulator), the operating system kernel can suspend threads because there are checks in place to ensure that these deadlocks can't happen. I don't know the details, but it probably involves masking interrupts at certain critical points, and probably not sharing the same mutexes between user-mode code and critical parts of the kernel scheduler. (In your case that would mean your scheduler could not use any of the same OS API functions, either directly or indirectly, as are allowed to be used by the user threads, in case they involve mutexes. This of course would be virtually impossible to achieve.)

The reason I asked in a comment whether you have any control over the user code compiler is that if you controlled the compiler then you could arrange for the user code to effectively mask interrupts for the duration of each instruction and only yield to another thread at well-defined points between instructions. This is how it is done in a control system that I work on.

The other aspect is platform dependence. In Linux and other unix-like operating systems, you have signals, which are like user-mode interrupts. You could potentially use signals to emulate context switching, although you would still have the same problem with mutexes. There is absolutely no equivalent on Windows (as far as I know) precisely because of the problem already stated. The nearest thing is an asynchronous procedure call, but this will run only when the thread has put itself into an alertable wait state (which means the thread is in a deterministic state and is now safe to interrupt).

I think you are going to have to re-think the whole concept so that your supervisory thread has the sort of privileged control above the user threads that the OS has in a non-emulated environment. That will probably involve replacing the compiler or the run-time libraries, or both, with something of your own making.

Comment: i totally agree with you that we 'can' use suspend API etc if we ensure that there will never be any deadlocks caused by it at any level. Actually i have seen a production level RTOS simulator source code which uses them. i think they would have done a bit of research on this suspend API issue before production and come to decision of using it,